# How Do I Run DOS Commands From VB with parameters

Tags: vb.net

i want to run dos command from VB , i try it my way but no success as am getting data from user in text boxes . TextBox1  and TextBox2  .... so please help

```
 Label1.Text = "Ready"
    Dim str As String
    str = "netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=val(TextBox1.Text) key=Val(TextBox2.Text)"
    Process.Start("cmd.exe", str)
```

Comment: do not know what you mean :D but am doing this in microsoft visual studio 2012 Visual Basic Project ... windows forms application ... a .vb script and .vb form design

Answer (score 2):

I use the shell command and it worked: `shell()`